# Web API EF MVC not returning rows after manipulation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Newbie MVC/EF developer here and came across an issue. I created a simple example of an MVC API which just reads a table in the db and returns it in XML format for the calling party. It works well, but when I manipulate/change the content of the in memory resultset, the API return is empty. So what I try to do is query the database, loop through the records and update the values in memory (not in db). So far I have this, and the values assinged are correct, but I get nothing back in the end.

The code:

```
namespace app.Repositories
{
    public class ParameterSets : IParameterSets
    {
        readonly RijndaelEcrypt re = new RijndaelEcrypt();
        public IEnumerable<ParameterSet> ListofParameterSet()

        using (DbconnectionContext context = new DbconnectionContext())
        {
            var listofparameters = from parameters in context.ParameterSet
            select parameters;

            foreach(ParameterSet x in listofparameters)
            {
                x.DbServerDatabase = re.Encrypt(x.DbServerDatabase);
                x.DbServerInstance = re.Encrypt(x.DbServerInstance);
                x.DbServerPassword = re.Encrypt(x.DbServerPassword);
                x.DbServerUser = re.Encrypt(x.DbServerUser);
            }

            return listofparameters.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your input and very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating in a `foreach` loop is not possible. You can use a `for` or a LINQ `Select`

```
for (var i = 0; i < listofparameters.Count; i++)
{       
    listofparameters[i].DbServerDatabase = re.Encrypt(listofparameters[i].DbServerDatabase);
    listofparameters[i].DbServerInstance = re.Encrypt(listofparameters[i].DbServerInstance);
    listofparameters[i].DbServerPassword = re.Encrypt(listofparameters[i].DbServerPassword);
    listofparameters[i].DbServerUser = re.Encrypt(listofparameters[i].DbServerUser);
}
```

or

```
var encryptedParams = listofparameters.Select(x => new ParameterSet ()
    {
        DbServerDatabase = re.Encrypt(x.DbServerDatabase),
        DbServerInstance = re.Encrypt(x.DbServerInstance),
        DbServerPassword = re.Encrypt(x.DbServerPassword),
        DbServerUser = re.Encrypt(x.DbServerUser)
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of them work. The for loop^solution give an error 'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type IQueryable<ParameterSet>. the LINQ solution doesn't return the ecrypted values; just the values like retrieved from the db

Comment: Sorry - I thought you called `.ToList()` on the `listofparameters` before the for loop, now I see you do it after. Put it before the loop and it should work

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks for the help :) I was close but not quite there.